# Java OpenCV - detecting ROI, creating submat and copy to original mat

Tags: java, opencv, blur, mat

I'm trying to blur the faces of all people detected by the webcam.
The problem is that when the webcam detect a face the program shows the crop mat with the blur face.

I tried to put the blur face into the original mat but it doesn't work.

```
for(Rect rect : faces.toArray()){
    Imgproc.rectangle(frame, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0,0,255),3);
    Rect rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y , rect.width, rect.height);
    Mat imageROI = grayFrame.submat(rectCrop);

    //frame is the original mat with the correct size
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageROI, frame, new Size(55, 55), 55);
}
```

No face detection:

[image: No face detection]

With face detection:

[image: With face detection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this constructor of Mat

```
Mat imageROI = new Mat(grayFrame,rectCrop);
```

instead of

```
 Mat imageROI = grayFrame.submat(rectCrop);
```

The constructor gives you  reference to the data matrix that is owned by grayFrame. so any modifications to submat will effect the bigmat.The `submat` gives copy of the grayFrame data matrix for the crop rectangle. So the modifications on the submat will not effect the bigmat.